# How to prove that 3-CNF is satisfiable using Hall's marriage theorem?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, satisfiability

> Given a 3-CNF formula where each variable from variables $x_1,...,x_n$ appears exactly 3 times in different clauses $c_1,...,c_m$, and each clause contains exactly 3 different variables, prove that the formula is satisfiable using Hall's marriage theorem.

Firstly, because each variable appears in 3 different clauses and each clause contains 3 different variables it follows that $n=m$.

We can define $X=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, $Y=\{c_1,...,c_n\}$ and a bipartite graph $G=(X\cup Y, E)$ where $E=\{(x_i, c_j)|x_i\in c_j\}$.

Let $P$ be a set of clauses, $P \subseteq Y$.

In order to use Hall's theorem I need to prove that $|\Gamma(P)|\ge |P|$, where $|\Gamma(P)|$ means the neighborhood of $P$ (all adjacent vertices)  but I'm really not sure how to prove that using [graph theoretic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem#Graph_theoretic_formulation) formulation of Hall's theorem.

Comment: What does it mean $\Gamma(P)$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I added the explanation in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already set the problem up, and the rest is a classic corollary of Hall's theorem:

> Every $k$-regular bipartite graph has a perfect matching.

In case you are unfamiliar: here $k$-regular means that the degree of each vertex is $k$ and a perfect matching is a collection of disjoint edges that covers all the vertices. You have a $3$-regular bipartite graph, and a perfect matching would assign to each clause a unique variable, which you would then set to be true or false to make that clause true.

Proof: Let $P \subseteq Y$. Since the degree of each vertex of $P$ is $k$, there are $|P|\cdot k$ many edges between $P$ and $\Gamma(P)$. But since the degree of each vertex of $\Gamma(P)$ is $k$ and $P \subseteq \Gamma(\Gamma(P))$, there are at most $|\Gamma(P)|\cdot k$ many edges between $P$ and $\Gamma(P)$. This implies that $|P|\cdot k \leq |\Gamma(P)| \cdot k$, or $|P| \leq |\Gamma(P)|$ as desired.

Note that we can apply this result repeatedly: a $k$-regular bipartite graph minus a perfect matching is a $(k-1)$-regular bipartite graph. Thus we can partition the edges of a $k$-regular bipartite graph into $k$ perfect matchings (this is known as a 1-factorization). This means that there are at least 3 ways your 3-CNF is satisfiable!

Comment: so in the matching each clause would be matched to only one variable? more specifically would it be a one-to-one map between clauses and variables?

Comment: Yes. Since the bipartite graph has the same number of vertices on each side (same number of variables as clauses), a perfect matching gives a bijection between the two sides.

Comment: Also why the fact that $P \subseteq \Gamma(\Gamma(P))$ imply that $|P|\le |\Gamma(P)|$?

Comment: There is a step you're missing. There are exactly $|\Gamma(P)| \cdot k$ edges between $\Gamma(P)$ and $\Gamma(\Gamma(P))$, so since $P \subseteq \Gamma(\Gamma(P))$, there are at most $|\Gamma(P)| \cdot k$ edges between $\Gamma(P)$ and $P$. But since there are exactly $|P|\cdot k$ edges between $\Gamma(P)$ and $P$ (see the above argument again), $|P| \cdot k \leq |\Gamma(P)| \cdot k$.

Comment: @Yos another way of saying what’s happening: the number of edges between $P$ and $\Gamma(P)$ is at most the number of edges between $\Gamma(P)$ and $\Gamma(\Gamma(P))$. The desired inequality follows.